# react.jsx.TransformError: or: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'f.JSXTransformer=e()')

Tags: python, reactjs

I am following https://github.com/reactjs/react-python to compiler my jsx to js, but I got error messages, and the stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/react/jsx.py", line 56, in transform
    return JSXTransformer().transform(jsx_path, js_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/react/jsx.py", line 43, in transform
    js = self.transform_string(i.read())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/react/jsx.py", line 39, in transform_string
    raise TransformError(e.message[7:])
react.jsx.TransformError: or: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'f.JSXTransformer=e()')
```

Could any help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: You have to provide code from jsx file to get accurate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the node binary is reachable on your path.